# How to read a JS var from GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I have a requirement that needs to read a variable (***apiCall***) that is set in javascript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oidValue = "";
    var apiCall = false;

    function firePatientSearch(lastname, firstname, dob, mrn, OID) {
        apiCall = true;
        SUBMIT_PDQ.focus();
        SUBMIT_PDQ.click();
        }
</script>
```

From my GWT code I do this:

```
public native Boolean isAPICall()/*-{
    return $wnd.apiCall;
}-*/;
```

But the answer is always false! I read call ***isAPICall()*** after issuing the JS function ***firePatientSearch***. It should be true or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: seems I cannot read a bool, only strings. When I changed to this it started working again.

Answer (score 2):

Try using boolean instead of Boolean as return value of your JSNI method.

```
public native boolean isAPICall()/*-{
    return $wnd.apiCall;
}-*/;
```

According to the [Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#passing-javascript), only the  primitive boolean is supported.

Edit: Checks for undefined (and other special cases) must be done in your JSNI code.